# Did Android optimize the rasterization of Vector Drawable?

Tags: android, rasterizing, android-vectordrawable

I want to migrate all my pictures to Vector Drawable. I know it will have a hit to the app startup time because it renders them the PNGs when app start. But what I didn't know is will Android cache these PNG per session? or per app lifetime?

It makes sense to cache them per lifetime since I don't see why user device is going to change.

All it said is as long as you keep the size the same, Android will reuse them.

Comment: check this article https://medium.com/upday-devs/optimizing-the-performance-of-vector-drawables-680a4c456286#.qzqthgf63

Comment: Thanks Zilk. I read it before. Unfortunately, it did not has the answer I wanted. I guess I really have to benchmark it myself to find out when app restart (cold one, e.g. after kill), does it still has the slow down.